# SSH connection leaving stale sessions on the server

Tags: java, ssh

I am programatically trying to connect to ssh running remotely. I am running a tomcat server instance. Whenever i need, from the code, i create a session, connect and execute a few commands that are needed within a try block and then close off the connection that was created as part of the finally block at all the places. Things work well and fine, but at some cases when i execute a **w** or **netstat** command on the ssh server, I see a few connections that are idle for more than a few hours and the ip address of those connections shows the connection to be from my application, but my java heap dump does not show any instance of my class in the memory, but i see ganymed related class instances in the heap.

I am using ganymed-ssh-260 library to connect to my server.

Is this something that someone has already seen?

Attaching the code snippet that connectes the ssh to the server

```
public class SSHExecutor{

private OutputStream stdin;
private InputStream stdout;
private InputStream stderr;
private Session sess;    
private Connection conn;    

    public void createConnection(String hostname, int port, String userName, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            conn = new Connection(hostname, port);          
            final boolean isAuthenticated = publicKeyAccess(hostname, userName, password);
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
            }

            sess = conn.openSession();
            final int xWidth = 90;
            final int yWidth = 80;
            sess.requestPTY("dumb", xWidth, yWidth, 0, 0, null);
            sess.startShell();
            stdin = sess.getStdin();
            stdout = sess.getStdout();
            stderr = sess.getStderr();

            isConnectionActive = true;
            final String response = getResponse();
            if (response != null && response.toLowerCase().contains(ObjectConstants.CURRENTLY_NOT_AVAILABLE)) {
                throw new IOException("Account is currently not available.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Problem in CreateConnection", e);
            isConnectionActive = false;         
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        final StringBuffer responseData = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            final int byteValue = 8192;
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[byteValue];
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if ((stdout.available() == 0) && (stderr.available() == 0)) {
                        int conditions = 1;
                        if (promptString != null && promptString.length() > 0) {
                            final int fiveThousand = 5000;
                            conditions = sess.waitForCondition(ChannelCondition.STDOUT_DATA
                                    | ChannelCondition.STDERR_DATA | ChannelCondition.EOF, fiveThousand);
                        } else {
                            conditions = sess.waitForCondition(ChannelCondition.STDOUT_DATA
                                    | ChannelCondition.STDERR_DATA | ChannelCondition.EOF,
                                    ObjectConstants.THOUSAND_FIVE_HUNDRED);
                        }

                        if ((conditions & ChannelCondition.TIMEOUT) != 0) {
                            break;
                        }

                        if ((conditions & ChannelCondition.EOF) != 0) {
                            if ((conditions & (ChannelCondition.STDOUT_DATA | ChannelCondition.STDERR_DATA)) == 0) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    while (stdout.available() > 0) {
                        final int len = stdout.read(buffer);
                        if (len > 0) {
                            responseData.append(new String(buffer, 0, len));
                        }
                    }

                    while (stderr.available() > 0) {
                        final int len = stderr.read(buffer);
                        if (len > 0) {
                            responseData.append(new String(buffer, 0, len));
                        }
                    }
                    if (promptString != null && promptString.length() > 0) {
                        if (responseData.indexOf(promptString) != -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Read Error :", e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("getResponse Error ", e);
        }
        return responseData.toString();
    }

    public String executeCommand(String command) throws IOException {
        String response = null;
        if (isConnectionActive && stdin != null) {
            try {
                stdin.write(command.getBytes());
                stdin.flush();
                response = getResponse();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                throw ie;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in executeCommandForPage()", e);
                response = e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            response = "Connection not active.";
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        if (stderr != null) {
            try {
                stderr.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in closeConnection()", e);
            }
        }
        if (stdout != null) {
            try {
                stdout.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in closeConnection()", e);
            }
        }
        if (stdin != null) {
            try {
                stdin.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in closeConnection()", e);
            }
        }
        if (sess != null) {
            try {
                sess.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in closeConnection()", e);
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in closeConnection()", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're creating a local `Connection` variable but you're testing what must be a member variable, which is always null, so you're never closing it.
2. If authentication fails you're leaking the connection.

Comment: Really sorry about that. That was a typo that had happened when i tried for a small debugging. It is actually a global Connection object that I instantiate within my createConnection(..) method.. I have corrected the code above as well..